# How to remove highlighted color of specific word in sentence keeping other words highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image]

Here I want to remove highlight color of "Basic life" word keeping other two highlighted words as it is.I have the range of word which I want to remove the highlight color.

Here is my Angular Code:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')
var sentenceToRemoveHighlight = cells[record['flag'] - 1].innerText
var subString = sentenceToRemoveHighlight.substring(record['startRange'], record['endRange'])
var hilightSubString = '<span class="hiliteBlank">' + subString + '</span>';
sentenceToRemoveHighlight = sentenceToRemoveHighlight.replace(subString, hilightSubString)
cells[record['flag'] - 1].innerHTML = sentenceToRemoveHighlight;
```

This code remove the highlight color of whole sentence as it is processing on innerText not on innerHTML.

Comment: this question is too user specific can you have some more info like a stackblitz link on how your are formulating it

Comment: I am using document.executeCommand() to highlight current selected word.To delete selected word I am taking whole sentence as string and replacing substring(word which I want to remove highlight) with unhighlighted word.

Comment: you should not be trying to access the document directly when using angular